# How to carry a Squash racket on Thai Airways?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, sport

I have asked one of my friends to bring along a Squash racket for me from China, and he will be coming via Thai Airways.

He has shown the concern that the racket will be damaged if carried along.

So I would like to know is it possible to carry the racket through a carry-on backpack, or to carry it in hands?

P.S: Squash rackets have maximum dimensions of 686 mm (27.0 in) long and 215 mm (8.5 in) wide, with a maximum strung area of 500 square centimeters (77.5 sq in). And the weight is around 250g.

Comment: What’s wrong with carrying it in the cabin? It’s a daily common item.

Comment: @HankyPanky its length is 68cm, and what I have gathered from Google is: Cabin baggage should have a maximum length of 56 cm

Comment: I'd ask the airline; from the web site, there's no mention of tennis/squash rackets
https://www.thaiairways.com/en_US/plan/travel_information/baggage.page

Comment: @HankyPanky also based on conversations with some security, it might be considered a weapon by some :/

Answer (score 2):

[This forum post from 2011](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/16630622-post3.html) says that the user contacted a Thai Airways representative in Hong Kong and was told that r**ackets should be checked-in since they exceed the allowed cabin baggage dimensions**:

> TENNIS RACQUETS:
>
> "Due tennis racquet is over-sized than the allowance of cabin baggage, it is required to checked as a checkin baggage."

This does put you at risk of having to check-in the racket, since as you said

> Squash rackets have maximum dimensions of 686 mm (27.0 in) long and 215 mm (8.5 in) wide

and [the maximum allowed dimensions for carry-on luggage are](https://www.thaiairways.com/en_GB/plan/travel_information/baggage.page?):

> maximum length 56 cm (22 inches), width 45 cm (18 inches), thickness 25 cm (10 inches).

To be sure, [try tweeting Thai Airways](https://twitter.com/ThaiAirways) asking them specifically about this problem. You might get an updated answer this way

As an alternative, the racket might just fit *diagonally* in a flat rectangular 56×45 cm box or carry on luggage, though -- and certainly would fit in the long diagonal of a 56×45×25 luggage. So you can try this solution.

Comment: The racket might just fit _diagonally_ in a flat rectangular 56×45 cm box, though -- and certainly would fit in the long diagonal of a 56×45×25 box. So keeping the box rectangular for the measurement would be the only problem.